# Design a 4-bit binary counter using D flip-flop

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, karnaugh-map, truth-table

I am learning logic circuit now.I am going to design a 4-bit binary counter with D-flip-flop.It counts from 0 to 15.And when the number reaches 15,the number wont change and remains 15.I am now working with the add function of the circuit,but I cant find where i get wrong.

This is the Truth Table I made.
[image]

The Karnaugh Map and expressions of all D and CP
[image]

Like you can see,when CP 1 activates Qa,CP2 gets activated due to (Qa !Qb),and CP3 gets activated then and CP4 got activated then.The result gets totally wrong!So can anyone points out my mistake?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to make this device. There are synchronous and asynchronous counters.

We will take the simplest example: to make a clock (counter), we need to change the D-triggers into T-triggers. This is done by connecting \$\small\overline{\text Q} \$ to the \$\small {\text D}\$ input.

The Data Trigger works in the following way: if there is a 1 on its \$\small {\text D}\$ input and it receives a clock signal, the 1 from the \$\small {\text D}\$ input will be transfered to \$\small {\text Q}\$ and \$\small\overline {\text Q}\$ will become 0.

The table for \$\small {\text Q}\$ is as follows:

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
```

\$\small\overline {\text Q}\$ will always be the opposite of \$\small {\text Q}\$.

The left-most trigger is the least significant bit. The right-most trigger is the most significant bit.

After \$\small {\text Q}\$ changes to 0, the \$\small\overline {\text Q}\$ changes to 1, since \$\small\overline {\text Q}\$ is connected to the \$\small {\text D}\$ input on the trigger. On the next clock impulse, the 1 from the \$\small {\text D}\$ input will be moved to the \$\small {\text Q}\$ output, and so on for every trigger.

The circuit is here:

[image]